# jQuery Serialize on an Array

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization

I have a webpage with the following input:

```
<input type='text' name='packagedims[]' value='1' id='packagedims' title='Package1' />
```

I'm using it in jQuery as so:

```
var packagedims = $('input#packagedims').serialize();
```

and then I'm using jQuery.ajax to post it to my php file:

```
'&packagedims=' + packagedims
```

(I know I could use Serialize() on the whole form but I'm modifying existing code so haven't got round to doing that yet. In the above line I'm sending individual variables to php.)

When I test the output using alert() I get the following:

```
&packagedims=packagedims%5B%5D=1&packagedims%5B%5D=2
```

I just wanted to check that this sort of output is correct and that using unSerialize() in my php file will be able to split this into a proper array.

Thank you,

Comment: Shouldn't it be like `packagedims%5B0%5D=1&packagedims%5B1%5D=2`? (index included)

Comment: that's what I was thinking actually...

Answer (score 4):

[`.serialize()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) already returns a string in the form of

```
key=value&key=value&...
```

**Don't** append to something else, otherwise it becomes

```
key=key=value&...
```

which is incorrect. So do not concatenate it with `'&packagedims='`.

There is no need to use any unserialize function in PHP. The data will be sent as GET or POST data and be available in PHP through `$_GET` or `$_POST`. E.g. if you make a POST request, `$_POST['packagedims']` will be an array containing the values.

[*Variables From External Sources*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.external.php) might be worth a read.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for that I have amended my code and will read up on what you have advised!

Comment: Should there be an index value between the %5D%5B values?

Comment: @rav: No, the names of the fields are `name='packagedims[]'`. jQuery will not not add anything to the name. And in PHP, if you want to add something to an array, you just write `array[] = something` so that is totally fine.